# How to retrieve all the ec2 security groups of aws tied to a aws account

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

We have separate AWS accounts for test, prelive and live. I want to get all the ec2 security groups for the running ec2 instances(not stopped ones) tied to a aws account (like test, prelive and live) and add the inbound security-group rules to each of the ec2 instance's ec2 security groups.

Each aws account can be spread across different AWS regions (example Singapore, Mumbai etc). For example AWS account prelive can be in us-east-1 (N-Virginia) and us-west-2 (Oregon). I checked the aws cli document to achieve this but did not get enough information.

Can anyone please help me in this regard with a small example if it is possible?

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: Your question is unclear -- are you trying to retrieve a **list** of security groups, or are you trying to **update** security groups? What have you tried so far? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details or to show us what you have tried. For tips on asking a good question, see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your request is somewhat complicated. You will have to write custom software to accomplish what you want.

However, I fail to understand why you would want to do this. Security groups are like firewalls. They should only allow the required traffic into an EC2 instance and not blindly support every configuration that you might want in the future. Design your security group rules with an architecture of "Least Privilege".

Software Considerations:

1) You will need to process each account separately using the Access Keys assigned for that account.

2) Then you will have to process the security groups for each VPC.

3) Then you will have to merge these rules into the target security groups.

Step 1 and 2 is very easy to do in Python or PHP or even the AWS CLI. Step 3 is more complicated (merging rule sets).

Answer (score -1):

One of the Simplest Way would be to create **Peering Connection between the VPCs.**

Peering Connections can be created across different AWS accounts very easily by referencing the VPC ID in the other account, and then you will need to login to that account and Accept/Approve the connection.

You Can Read [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html) for Details.

**Edit :** As per the comment Below I failed to Mention that it is possible when VPC Exist in Same Region Only.

Comment: VPC peering between regions is not possible.